# tasks in enumerate: problem with baselines if lineheight too big

Tags: tasks

I'm using tasks (https://github.com/cgnieder/tasks) in enumerate.

If the line-height is encreased (eg by a formula) the baseline of the first task is not on the item-baseline:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}
    \item\mbox{}\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep}
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task Baseline of task $= $ baseline of item
        \task $x$
    \end{tasks}
    \item\mbox{}\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep}
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task Baseline of task $\neq $ baseline of item
        \task $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x}}{y}$
    \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an object with sufficiently big height is inserted into a line `TeX` don't just use `\baselineskip`, but adds another space ensuring that consecutive lines aren't placed too close. Specifically, the distance between lines cannot be less than `\lineskiplimit`. You can set it to some negative value thus making `TeX` use `\baselineskip` only. For example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tasks}

\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item\mbox{}\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep}
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task Baseline of task $= $ baseline of item
        \task $x$
    \end{tasks}
    \item\mbox{}\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep}
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task Baseline of task $\neq $ baseline of item
        \task $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x}}{y}$
    \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

generates

[image]

In this case lines can overlap, by the way.